# How do I make the apple terminal window auto change colour scheme when I ssh to a specific server

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-leopard

When I ssh into a remote production server I would like the colour scheme of my terminal window to change to something brigh and scary, preferably red, to warn me that I am touching a live scary server.

How can I make it automatically detect that I have ssh'ed somewhere, and if that somewhere is on a specific list, change the colour scheme?

I want to update the Scheme of Terminal.app, not know how I would do this in a pure linux/unix env

Comment: Why is a pure linux/unix solution bad?

Comment: @Milhous Because OS X's Terminal.app offers far more style customizations than the *nix-based customizations do, from font & ANSI colors to line & character spacing to background color, opacity, & blur.  Terminal's styles look really good when adjusted tastefully, and many of us OS X users like our computers to look like they're from the 2010s, not the 1980s.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Put following script in `~/bin/ssh` (ensure `~/bin/` is checked before `/usr/bin/` in your PATH):

```
#!/bin/sh

HOSTNAME=`echo $@ | sed s/.*@//`

set_bg () {
  osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set background color of window 1 to $1"
}

on_exit () {
  set_bg "{0, 0, 0, 50000}"
}
trap on_exit EXIT

case $HOSTNAME in
  production1|production2|production3) set_bg "{45000, 0, 0, 50000}" ;;
  *) set_bg "{0, 45000, 0, 50000}" ;;
esac

/usr/bin/ssh "$@"
```

Remember to make the script executable by running `chmod +x ~/bin/ssh`

The script above extracts host name from line "username@host" (it assumes you login to remote hosts with "ssh user@host").

Then depending on host name it either sets red background (for production servers) or green background (for all other). As a result all your ssh windows will be with colored background.

I assume here your default background is black, so script reverts the background color back to black when you logout from remote server (see "trap on_exit").

Please, note however this script does not track chain of ssh logins from one host to another. As a result the background will be green in case you login to testing server first, then login to production from it.

Comment: You, sir, just made my day.

Comment: This is fine, but it changes every terminal background, not only the current one. Any clue on this?

Answer (score 42):

A lesser-known feature of Terminal is that you can set the name of a settings profile to a command name and it will select that profile when you create a new terminal via either **Shell > New Command…** or **Shell > New Remote Connection…**.

For example, duplicate your default profile, name it “ssh” and set its background color to red. Then use **New Command…** to run `ssh host.example.com`.

It also matches on arguments, so you can have it choose different settings for different remote hosts, for example.

Comment: I can't believe how useful this is. Just the thing I was looking for.

Comment: This is the best answer for me.  of note, the profile name can be a regex, e.g. 'ssh .*myserver.*' is matching 'ssh myserver', 'ssh -p 22 myserver.foo.com' etc.

Comment: Works great on Sierra. Trying to figure out now if I can shortcut the ssh somewhere instead of having to open New Remote Connection each time

Comment: unfortunately this leaves the colour set after the SSH session ends (e.g. if terminal reopens windows after a reboot, or the connection drops).

Answer (score 10):

Another solution is to set the colors straight in the ssh config file:

inside ~/.ssh/config

```
Host Server1
   HostName x.x.x.x
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile ~/Desktop/keys/1.pem
   PermitLocalCommand yes
   LocalCommand osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set background color of window 1 to {27655, 0, 0, -16373}"

Host Server2
   HostName x.x.x.x
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile ~/Desktop/keys/2.pem
   PermitLocalCommand yes
   LocalCommand osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set background color of window 1 to {37655, 0, 0, -16373}"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Far and away the simplest.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't change the colour back once you exit the ssh session. However I have managed to overcome this limitation by using a simple tool: https://github.com/drinchev/phook. This is my line in `~/.ssh/config`: `LocalCommand phook -a "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of window 1 to settings set \"Basic\"'" -e "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of window 1 to settings set \"SSH-Yellow\"'"`

Answer (score 9):

Here's a combined solution based on a couple of existing answers that handles the exit. Also includes a little extra if you don't want to deal with 16 bit color values.

This should be put in your *~/.bash_profile*

```
# Convert 8 bit r,g,b,a (0-255) to 16 bit r,g,b,a (0-65535)
# to set terminal background.
# r, g, b, a values default to 255
set_bg () {
    r=${1:-255}
    g=${2:-255}
    b=${3:-255}
    a=${4:-255}

    r=$(($r * 256 + $r))
    g=$(($g * 256 + $g))
    b=$(($b * 256 + $b))
    a=$(($a * 256 + $a))

    osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set background color of window 1 to {$r, $g, $b, $a}"
}

# Set terminal background based on hex rgba values
# r,g,b,a default to FF
set_bg_from_hex() {
    r=${1:-FF}
    g=${2:-FF}
    b=${3:-FF}
    a=${4:-FF}

    set_bg $((16#$r)) $((16#$g)) $((16#$b)) $((16#$s))
}

# Wrapping ssh command with extra functionality
ssh() {
    # If prod server of interest, change bg color
    if ...some check for server list
    then
        set_bg_from_hex 6A 05 0C
    end

    # Call original ssh command
    if command ssh "$@"
    then
        # on exit change back to your default
        set_bg_from_hex 24 34 52
    fi
}
```

- set_bg - takes 4 (8 bit) color values
- set_bg_from_hex - takes 4 hex values. most of my color references I use are in hex, so this just makes it easier for me. It could be taken a step further to actually parse #RRGGBB instead of RR GG BB, but it works well for me.
- ssh - wrapping the default ssh command with whatever custom logic you want. The if statement is used to handle the exit to reset the background color.

Comment: you can use `osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to get background color of window 1"` to get the original colors (in decimal)

Answer (score 8):

Combining answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166201/1024794) and [2](https://superuser.com/a/209920/195425) have the following:

Create `~/bin/ssh` file as described in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166201/1024794) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/39489571/1024794
log(){
  echo "$*" >> /tmp/ssh.log
}
HOSTNAME=`echo $@ | sed s/.*@//`
log HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME
# to avoid changing color for commands like `ssh user@host "some bash script"`
# and to avoid changing color for `git push` command:
if [ $# -gt 3 ] || [[ "$HOSTNAME" = *"git-receive-pack"* ]]; then
  /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
  exit $? 
fi

set_bg () {
  if [ "$1" != "Basic" ]; then
    trap on_exit EXIT;
  fi
  osascript ~/Dropbox/macCommands/StyleTerm.scpt "$1"
}

on_exit () {
  set_bg Basic
}


case $HOSTNAME in
  "178.222.333.44 -p 2222") set_bg "Homebrew" ;;
  "178.222.333.44 -p 22") set_bg "Ocean" ;;
  "192.168.214.111") set_bg "Novel" ;;
  *) set_bg "Grass" ;;
esac

/usr/bin/ssh "$@"
```

Make it executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/ssh`.

File `~/Dropbox/macCommands/StyleTerm.scpt` has the following content:

```
#https://superuser.com/a/209920/195425
on run argv
  tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of selected tab of front window to first settings set whose name is (item 1 of argv)
end run
```

Words `Basic, Homebrew, Ocean, Novel, Grass` are from mac os terminal settings <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>:
[image: terminal profiles]

Answer (score 5):

You can set the $PS1 variable in your .bashrc.

```
red='\e[0;31m'
PS1="$\[${red}\]"
```

EDIT:
  To do this open the Terminal.  Then say

```
#touch .bashrc
```

You can then open .bashrc in textEdit or in [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/download.html) and add the previous commands.

Comment: How exactly do I do this, and how does apple's terminal know to change its colour sceme too

Comment: create a file ~/.bashrc on the server you want to change to red. (not on your mac)

Answer (score 5):

### Set the terminal colours in the server's `/.bashrc`

I needed the same thing, something to make me aware that I was on a Staging or Production server and not in my Development environment, which can be very hard to tell, especially when in a Ruby console or something.

To accomplish this, I used the `setterm` command in my server's `~./bashrc` file to inverse the colours of the terminal when connecting and restore the colours when exiting.

#### ~/.bashrc

```bash
# Inverts console colours so that we know that we are in a remote server. 
# This is very important to avoid running commands on the server by accident.
setterm --inversescreen on

# This ensures we restore the console colours after exiting.
function restore_screen_colours {
  setterm --inversescreen off
}
trap restore_screen_colours EXIT
```

I then put this in all the servers' `~/.bashrc` files so that I know when my terminal is on a remote server or not.

Another bonus is that any of your development or devops team get the benefit of this without making it part of the onboarding process.

**Works great.**

Comment: All the other answers didn't work for me, this one did. Thank you sir!

Comment: @ripper234 You're welcome! Glad you found it way down here on the list. :)

Comment: Any idea how to configure it to be red/yellow on production/staging envs?

Comment: @ripper234 Not sure, but I'm sure you can use parts of the other answers to change the background colour or something.

Answer (score 2):

Xterm-compatible Unix terminals have standard escape sequences for setting the background and foreground colors. I'm not sure if Terminal.app shares them; it should.

```
case $HOSTNAME in
    live1|live2|live3) echo -e '\e]11;1\a' ;;
    testing1|testing2) echo -e '\e]11;2\a' ;;
esac
```

The second number specifies the desired color. 0=default, 1=red, 2=green, etc. So this snippet, when put in a shared .bashrc, will give you a red background on live servers and a green background on testing ones. You should also add something like this to reset the background when you log out.

```
on_exit () {
    echo -e '\e]11;0\a'
}
trap on_exit EXIT
```

---

EDIT: Google turned up a way to [set the background color using AppleScript](http://www.athensexchange.com/blog/155). Obviously, this only works when run on the same machine as Terminal.app. You can work around that with a couple wrapper functions:

```
set_bg_color () {
    # color values are in '{R, G, B, A}' format, all 16-bit unsigned integers (0-65535)
    osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set background color of window 1 to $1"
}

sshl () {
    set_bg_color "{45000, 0, 0, 50000}"
    ssh "$@"
    set_bg_color "{0, 0, 0, 50000}"
}
```

You'd need to remember to run sshl instead of ssh when connecting to a live server. Another option is to write a wrapper function for ssh that scans its arguments for known live hostnames and sets the background accordingly.

Comment: Link broken, I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1):

Why not just changing the shell prompt whenever you are logged in via SSH? There are usually specific shell variables: **SSH_CLIENT**, **SSH_CONNECTION**, **SSH_TTY**

Comment: Because that's very different than changing the terminal window's color.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the color of username and host machine name.

add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PS1=" \[\033[34m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[31m\]\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

The **first part** (purple colored) is what you're looking for.

**Preview:**
[image]

This is my preferred colors. You can customize each part of prompt's color by changing `m` codes (e.g. `34m`) which are ANSI color codes.

**List of ANSI Color codes:**

- Black: 30m
- Red: 31m
- Green: 32m
- Yellow: 33m
- Blue: 34m
- Purple: 35m
- Cyan: 36m
- White: 37m

Answer (score 0):

All the applescript-based answers I've seen on the SO family suffer a reliance on Terminal's "Window 1", which is the currently focused window.  The problem is that if your ssh session closes while you've got a different window focused, the message gets sent to the wrong window.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76443239/230851) to a question of mine, I'm finding the following approach to be much more robust in the face of remote disconnect.

```
##########################################################################################################
# MacOS: sets the visual profile of the terminal window to a particular color while SSH'ing into another host.
# usage:
# 1. set up a terminal profile named "ssh_remote"  which is how you'd like the window to appear when ssh'd.
# 2. set up a terminal profile named "ssh_local"   which is how you'd like the window to appear when not ssh'd.
# Thanks to @Philippe on S.O. for help with osascript. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76443239/230851
function ssh() {
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of (the first window whose tty of tab 1 contains "'"$(tty)"'") to settings set "ssh_remote"'
    command ssh "$@"
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of (the first window whose tty of tab 1 contains "'"$(tty)"'") to settings set "ssh_local"'
}
```