# Change background of Terminal.app from the commandline

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to change the background color of Terminal.app from the shell?
If so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set background color of window 1 to {0,45000,0,0}"

[(Can't take the credit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157959/how-do-i-make-the-apple-terminal-window-auto-change-colour-scheme-when-i-ssh-to-a)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics, but I imagine you'd want to write an AppleScript program which you invoke from your shell script. The AppleScript would "Tell" Terminal to change its background colour.