# AppleScript - send a message to the terminal window a bash script is running in, even when that window does not have focus

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript, profile

Update: cloned to here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460841/209336

---

I'd like to have a bash script along the lines of this:

```
# set terminal window profile to profile2
sleep 300
# set terminal window profile to profile1
```

during that sleep, I might go off and start using a different application than Terminal, or I might be using a different Window of Terminal.  So the approaches which send a message to the active or front terminal window don't work.  Can I grab the current terminal window ID at the start and re-use it later ?

Comment: [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) might be a better forum for this question.

Comment: thanks! https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460841/209336

Comment: Either site is fine. Both sites is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tty` to identify the window.

Save following script to `test.sh` and run it with `bash test.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of (the first window whose tty of tab 1 contains "'"$(tty)"'") to settings set "Basic"'

echo "You can switch to another windows"

sleep 6

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of (the first window whose tty of tab 1 contains "'"$(tty)"'") to settings set "Grass"'
```

**Update**

Sonoma version :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FUNCTION='
on findTTYWindow(input_tty)
    tell application "Terminal"
        set theWindows to every window of it
        repeat with theWindow in theWindows
            if tty of tab 1 of theWindow contains input_tty then
                return theWindow
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end findTTYWindow'

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of my findTTYWindow("'"$(tty)"'") to settings set "Basic"'"$FUNCTION"
    
echo "You can switch to another windows"
        
sleep 6     
                
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of my findTTYWindow("'"$(tty)"'") to settings set "Grass"'"$FUNCTION"
```

Comment: this is super interesting, thank you. I haven't had a moment to try it yet, but I definitely will.

Comment: this works very well in testing. thank you!

Comment: Since updating to Sonoma, the osascript lines in this fail for me with `execution error: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)` .  I've poked around a bit but without success. Do you have any pointers ?

Comment: stunning ! thank you.  I would not have been able to make that work.